# Trying to save inputs to radio buttons

Tags: html

I am a student learning html. Our homework is to create a survey using html. I am creating a survey using html. My survey consist of an image and several radio buttons. How do i save the answers of the radio buttons? Can I save it to a CSV file? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few options but you cant do it with **HTML** alone...i don't know your technical abilities so i am gonna mention a few of them.

1. You can use JavaScript combined with the **localstorage** API.
2. You could submit the form and store it on the server with some sort of database.
3. You could also store it in a cookie, although cookies are easy to tamper with.